# Prove that $\Bbb Q$ is an injective object in $\Bbb Z\text{-mod}$ using the following definition.

Tags: category-theory, modules, homology-cohomology, group-homomorphism, injective-module

How can I show that $\Bbb Q$ is an injective object in $\Bbb Z\text{-mod}$ using the following definition: $A$ is an injective object in $\Bbb Z\text{-mod}$ iff the morphism Hom$_{\Bbb Z}(\Bbb Z,A) \rightarrow$ Hom$_{\Bbb Z}(J,A); g\mapsto g \circ i$ is surjective, in which $i:J \rightarrow \Bbb Z; j \mapsto j$ (inclusion). I found the same question which is solved using Baer's criterion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2097288/how-to-prove-that-mathbbq-is-an-injective-mathbbz-module-via-this-defi), and I do note the similarity between Baer's criterion and the definition I wrote, but I can't understand how to prove the surjective part.

Comment: Baer's criterion is exactly your definition

Comment: Oh, that explains the similarity! But how do I prove that Hom$_{\Bbb Z}(\Bbb Z,A) \rightarrow$ Hom$_{\Bbb Z}(J,A)$ is surjective?

Comment: Do you know what ideals $J$ of $\mathbb Z$ look like ? Do you know what morphisms $\mathbb Z\to A$ look like ?

Comment: I know that ideals $J$ of $\Bbb Z$ is defined as $n\Bbb Z$ and we can define $\Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb Q$ as $z \mapsto zq$ in which $q \in \Bbb Q$. So, from these definitions, we can say that $J \mapsto \Bbb Q$ as $j \mapsto jq$ (composed with inclusion), with $j \in n\Bbb Z$. Is this morphism surjective by definition?

Comment: No, $J\cong \mathbb Z$ via $n\mapsto 1$, so a morphism $J\to \mathbb Q$ has the form $j\mapsto \frac j n q$ for some fixed $q$